# contextMenu(forSelectionType:menu:primaryAction:) closure passes the incorrect number of selected items if selection modified programmatically

Tags: swiftui

Click "Select All" then long press on an item. The badge on the contextMenu displayed is incorrect as well as the count of the `Set` passed to the `menu` closure.

It only produces the correct count if each item is selected manually by the user. Scrolling manually before activating the contextMenu seems to add some to the count, but this doesn't hold for long lists.

Any workaround for this (probably) Apple bug so the badge displays the correct number?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let rows = (0..<4000).map{ "Row: \($0)" }
    @State var selection: Set<String> = []
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(selection: $selection) {
                ForEach(rows, id: \.self) { row in
                    Text(row)
                }
            }.contextMenu(forSelectionType: String.self) { contextMenuRows in
                Button("Number of rows in the contextMenu: \(contextMenuRows.count)") {}
                Button("Number of rows in selection: \(selection.count)") {}
            }.toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    if selection.count != rows.count {
                        Button("Select All") { selection = Set(rows) }
                    } else {
                        Button("Deselect All") { selection = [] }
                    }
                }
                
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    EditButton()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```